# Spring 3 bind obscures real values of command object

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a controller that allows users to add or edit an entity. I've removed myForm.myEntity.name from myForm but spring still shows it when the spring:bind tag is used. See the example below:

The snippet below outputs a value:

```
<spring:bind path="myForm.myEntity.name">
<h1>${status.value}</h1>
</spring:bind>
```

The snippet below doesn't:

```
<c:out value="${myForm.myEntity.name}"/>
```

I would expect both items not to output a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for these items in the page or request scope.
I believe that's where Spring-MVC has placed them, by default.

For example,